# Deploying Yeoman app to EB instance

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, yeoman

Does any one know how to "flawlessly" deploy a yeoman app to an AWS EB instance?

I've been looking online for months and tried multiple tutorials and haven't figured this out yet. I have a yeoman application I'm trying to deploy using Elastic beanstalk. I have deployed this app on heroku so I understand everything is based on the "dist" folder. I tried using Amazon's interface to upload a zip of the dist folder but it now has time out errors. I'm really confused and don't know what else to do. All help is appreciated.

Comment: yeoman is just a generator right? What's the app that you've generated? express? hapi? angular?

Comment: It's using angular